# Compare User Input with WordPress Meta Key Value

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-key

I have searched, but could not find it anywhere,

I need a function to compare, user's input with a meta key value, and then process.

For example, user will type 5000 in given box. User will see the result according to if specific user meta key value is greater, lesser or equals to 5000.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Use get_post_meta();

[Function ref. get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

You can compare dynamically with ajax